# Angular 2 - unique service instances for each module

Tags: angular, typescript

got the problem - i'm need get different instance of my service for different modules, but if i'm share service in modules, got the one instance of service for all my modules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ServiceComponent, Service2Component ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ UserService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

so, if i'm use provider here, or in one of the modules of following components - ServiceComponent, Service2Component - i'm got the one instance of UserService.

I can get unique instance only if use this service in all @Components without define it in modules, like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'service2test',
  template: `<h1>Hello, {{user}}.<br>ServiceComponentValue: {{value}}</h1>`,
  providers: [ UserService ]
})
```

my question is - is it possible define service in modules, and get unique value for each module?

service that I used for the test:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  userName = 'Sherlock Holmes';
  value: number;

  constructor() {
    this.value = Math.random()*100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yu can create new instance of service for each component without inject singleton dependency.

```
export class MyComponent {

  userService: UserService;

  constructor () {
    this.userService = new UserService();
  }

}
```